# How can i increment a value of a column on update?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper, hibernate-mapping

I have "REJECT_COUNT" and "VALUE" and 3 more columns.Value is the primary key in the table.I want "rejected_count" to be 1 on insert.It should get auto incremented by 1 on updating the same row.How can i do this in Hibernate freamework?
Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Better than what? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `REJECT_COUNT` to have value 1 on insert then you can create the table with `DEFAULT` clause. For updating the `REJECT_COUNT` on each update you can create an `UPDATE TRIGGER` on the table.

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_TABLE(VALUE NUMBER,
                        REJECT_COUNT NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
                        A NUMBER,
                        B NUMBER,
                        C NUMBER,
                        CONSTRAINT DAT_PK PRIMARY KEY (VALUE));

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DATA_TABLE_TRIGGER BEFORE UPDATE ON DATA_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

BEGIN

  :NEW.REJECT_COUNT := :OLD.REJECT_COUNT + 1;

END;
```